# Standardize-back the Standard deviation

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, normalization, back-transformation

I run an lmer model using standardized data like `scale(y) ~ 1 + (1|categorical)`
Now, I have a standard deviation for the random effect in normalized world but I would like to transform it back to original scale. By trying `z_sd * sd(y) + mean(y)` I am getting something that looks more like the `var` and not the `sd`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Take as example [this one,](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/tutorial_rstanarm.html) and the model `course ~ 1 + (1 | school)`
The Std.Dev. of School intercept is 8.674, now the `scale(course) ~ 1 + (1 | school)` will return a Std.Dev. for School intercept 0.5315.

However, I can't scale back the Std.Dev using the `school_sd * sd(course) + mean(course)`

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean by "I am getting something that looks more like the var and not the sd."?

Comment: @Firebug, sorry for the confusion, I want to scale back the estimated from the model standard deviation. However, by multiplying the estimated_sd with the original_sd and by adding the original_mean I get something too high that looks like the variance and not the standard deviation.

Comment: "Now, I have a standard deviation in normalized world but I would like to transform it back to original scale" There is information missing here. What exactly do you have a standard deviation of? Do you actually mean the standard error of a regression coefficient? Or perhaps the standard deviation of the model residuals? Maybe the standard error of a prediction? Your proposed equation `z_sd * sd(y) + mean(y)` demonstrates a lack of understanding what a standard deviation is and how it is calculated.

Comment: Is there some reason why you used standardization in the first place? Statistical analysis can be hard enough without getting caught up in this type of numerical confusion. Standardization is seldom needed for regression models. When it is important, for example in penalized regressions like ridge and lasso, the standardization and later back-correction is usually a default of the process. Don't make life harder for yourself that is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the case of [this example](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/tutorial_rstanarm.html) the Std Dev can be standardized back by multiplying it with the sd of the original scale.

So, for example

```
M3 <- lmer(formula = course ~ 1 + female + (1 + female | school), 
           data = GCSE, # the GCSE data are coming from example on the link
           REML = FALSE)
print(M3, digits = 10)

M31 <- lmer(formula = scale(course) ~ 1 + female + (1 + female | school), 
           data = GCSE, 
           REML = FALSE)
print(M31, digits = 10)
```

the SD for the original scale is

```
GCSE$course %>% sd(na.rm = T) %>% print(digits = 10)
```

and by multiplying it with any SD from M31 I get the same SD from M3.

And here a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2AM4TE84ik) talking about it (it's the last example).